# What are the differences between vue-hooks and vue-property-decorator?

Tags: vue.js

I want to separate my logic from the component in vue.

What I have in mind is this:

- One file for HTML template, the data pass as props.
- Another file that has a lot of functions and getters that gets the data from the store/API.

So after I search a lot I understand I need something like "hooks in reacts".

What I find is [u3u/vue-hooks](https://github.com/u3u/vue-hooks).

My question is what are the benefits to use this idea/library? cause it seems like I do the same with and without vue-hooks.

for example:

foo.ts:

```
import { computed, defineComponent } from '@vue/composition-api';

export default defineComponent({
  name: 'foo',
  props: {
    icon: {
      type: String,
      default: '',
    },
  },
  setup(props) {
    const iconName = computed(() => props.icon);
    return {
      iconName,
    };
  },
});
```

and foo.vue:

```
<template>
  <div>{{iconName}}</div>
</template>

<script lang="ts" src="./foo.ts">
</script>

<style lang="scss">
</style>
```

So until here, I separate the logic from the component and I can choose which file to attach the view.

But I can do it with the class as well.

just to change the foo.ts file to:

```
import { Component, Prop, Vue } from 'vue-property-decorator';

@Component
export default class Foo extends Vue {}
```

I would like it if anyone explains to me - if hooks are the way to separate the logic from the UI? and should I use vue-hooks to do it?

Comment: one thing is Vue 3 with composition-api and the another is Vue 2.x with TS class syntax that is deprecated.

Comment: So its just "how do you write your components?", not for separation?

Comment: No, they don't have anything to do with separation (so they don't in React). u3u/vue-hooks is just third-party set of helpers that work similarly to React custom hooks.